# Ternary operators test case with jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I want write a jest test case for following case as it show branch coverage `50%` and point out for this code.

```
render() {
        const {
          isExit
        } = data;
        const text = isExit ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

or

```
<LabelValue label="New Line" value={isExit ? 'Yes' : 'No'} />
```

**test case**

```
it('Should display the data if API status is complete', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowWithTheme(<DataPage
      orderDetail={{ isExit: true}}
      theme={theme}
    />);

    // what to write here?   
  });
```

Comment: You could try: `wrapper.setProps({orderDetail: {isExit: false}});` `wrapper.update();` to trigger the other case.

Comment: @izb; yeah but what should I test after wrapper.update()

Comment: `expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()`

Comment: Why are you using `shallowWithTheme` instead of just `shallow`?

Comment: @RyanWalker: I am using styled-component for my component which required theme prop

Answer (score 0):

```
expect(wrapper.text()).to.equal('Yes');
expect(wrapper.text()).to.equal('No');
```

Answer (score 0):

### Test both conditions:

```js
  it('Should display the data if API status is complete', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowWithTheme(<DataPage
      orderDetail={{ isExit: true}}
      theme={theme}
    />);

    expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot(); // 1st snapshot
    wrapper
      .setProps({orderDetail: {isExit: false}, theme})
    // check your snapshot with new props :)
    expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot(); // 2nd snapshot
  });
```

Good Luck...